# Converting LINQ (OrderBy/ThenBy) Code to CompareTo

Tags: c#, linq, icomparable

I have written a generic sort funciton to sort list and dicitonary. But LINQ doesnt works on Unity due to JIT errors. I want to have the same generics and convert it into myList.Sort() which uses CompraeTo. But Im unable to figure out how to accomplish this as generic as this.

```
    public static List<T> MySort<T>(this List<T> source, Type typeOfObject, bool isAscending = false, params string[] param) 
{
    if(param.Length == 0)
        return source;

    if (isAscending)
    {
        var temp = source.OrderBy (a => (typeOfObject.GetProperty (param [0])).GetValue (a, null));

        for (int i=1; i<param.Length; i++)
        {
            var myVar = i;
            temp = temp.ThenBy((a => (typeOfObject.GetProperty(param[myVar])).GetValue (a, null)));
        }
        return temp.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        var temp = source.OrderByDescending (a => (typeOfObject.GetProperty (param [0])).GetValue (a, null));
        for (int i=1; i<param.Length; i++)
        {
            var myVar = i;
            temp.ThenByDescending((a => (typeOfObject.GetProperty(param[myVar])).GetValue (a, null)));
        }
        return temp.ToList();
    }
}
```

USage of this function

```
RealEstateItems.MySort(typeof(mIsoObjectExt), true, "UnlockLevel", "Coins", "Diamonds");
```

My current CompareTo Approac

```
myList.Sort ((a,b) => {
int result = ((a.Value) as mIsoObjectExt).UnlockLevel.CompareTo(((b.Value) as mIsoObjectExt).UnlockLevel);
//  result == 0 ? result = a.Value.Coins.CompareTo(a.Value.Coins);
if(result == 0)
{
    result = ((a.Value) as mIsoObjectExt).Coins.CompareTo(((b.Value) as mIsoObjectExt).Coins);
}
else
{
    return result;
}
if(result == 0)
{
    return ((a.Value) as mIsoObjectExt).Diamonds.CompareTo(((b.Value) as mIsoObjectExt).Diamonds);
}
return result;
});
```

But Im not satisfied with this i have to do this every time i have to sort even on the same properties. Basically i want to make something like above that i tell the function the type its properties to sort on and it sorts. How can i do this with Compare/CompareTo?

Answer (score 1):

So we're going to need a few different building blocks to begin with.  First off, what you're really doing here is sorting each item on a collection of values, as is seen in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587580/1159478).  We can pull the solution from there to have a comparer for sorting items based on a collection of values:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IComparer<T> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IComparer<T> compareer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        using (var first = x.GetEnumerator())
        using (var second = x.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var firstHasMore = first.MoveNext();
                var secondHasMore = second.MoveNext();
                if (!firstHasMore && !secondHasMore)
                    return 0;
                var lengthComparison = firstHasMore.CompareTo(secondHasMore);
                if (lengthComparison != 0)
                    return lengthComparison;
                var nextComparison = comparer.Compare(first.Current, second.Current);
                if (nextComparison != 0)
                    return nextComparison;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We also want a way of creating a `Comparison<T>` delegate (which `List.Sort` accepts) from a projection delegate.  This method is simple enough to write:

```
public static Comparison<T> CreateComparison<T, TKey>(Func<T, TKey> selector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    return (a, b) => comparer.Compare(selector(a), selector(b));
}
```

It'll also be useful for us to be able to reverse a `Comparison<T>` (to handle descending ordering):

```
public static Comparison<T> Reverse<T>(this Comparison<T> comparison)
{
    return (a, b) => comparison(b, a);
}
```

Now to pull all of the pieces together.  We can create a comparison that, for the projection, projects each item into a sequence of values that represent fetching each of the property names from the item using reflection.  We can then reverse the comparer if we need a descending sort.

```
public static void MySort<T>(this List<T> source,
    bool isAscending = false,
    params string[] properties)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var comparison = CreateComparison((T item) =>
        properties.Select(prop => type.GetProperty(prop).GetValue(item)),
        new SequenceComparer<object>());
    if (!isAscending)
        comparison = comparison.Reverse();
    source.Sort(comparison);
}
```

---

Note that if you can also use the sequence comparer to simplify the LINQ approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyOrdering<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    bool isAscending = false,
    params string[] properties)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    Func<T, IEnumerable<object>> selector = item =>
        properties.Select(prop => type.GetProperty(prop).GetValue(item))
        .ToList();

    if (isAscending)
        return source.OrderBy(selector, new SequenceComparer<object>());
    else
        return source.OrderByDescending(selector, new SequenceComparer<object>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Servy's approach with reflection. If you decide against reflection, you can use the below approach, but it still needs the comparison to be provided from the caller.

```
public class MultiValueComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
   private IEnumerable<Comparison<T>> _comparisons;

   public MultiValueComparer(IEnumerable<Comparison<T>> comparisons)
   {
      _comparisons = comparisons;
   }

   public int Compare(T x, T y)
   {
     foreach (var comparison in _comparisons)
     {
        var result = comparison(x, y);
        if (result != 0)
           return result;
     }
     return 0;
   }
}
```

An extension method which takes a variable number of parameters

```
public static void Sort<T>(List<T> source, params Comparison<T>[] comparisons)
{
   if (comparisons.Count() == 0)
      return;

   source.Sort(new MultiValueComparer<T>(comparisons));
}
```

Usage:

Ascending Order:

```
Sort(samples, (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name), (x, y) => x.Test.CompareTo(y.Test));
```

Descending Order:

```
Sort(samples, (x, y) => y.Name.CompareTo(x.Name), (x, y) => y.Test.CompareTo(x.Test));
```